# Problems adding custom libraries in my Cocoa project in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, opencv, homebrew

I have some problems with adding custom libraries to my Cocoa project in XCode.

I'm using:
• OSX Lion 10.7.4 (11E53)
• XCode 4.3.3 (4E3002)
• OpenCV 2.4.1

**Here's what I did:**

1. Installed OpenCV through Homebrew in my Terminal with the following command (took 12.6 minutes :P):

   $ brew install opencv
2. Made a new Cocoa project in XCode (~/Documents/Objective-C/MyProject)
3. Copied OpenCV libraries:

   $ cp -R /usr/local/Cellar/opencv ~/Documents/MyProject/MyProject
4. In my XCode project settings I went to: *Targets -> MyProject*
5. Clicked the + in the Linked Frameworks and Libraries section
6. In the popup screen I clicked Add Other…
7. As path I chose: ~/Documents/MyProject/MyProject/opencv
8. Clicked the tab: *Build Settings*
9. In the search field entered:

   header search
10. Switched the option *Always Search User Paths* to *YES*
11. Double clicked in the empty space right of *Header Search Paths* and added (+) and check an entry:

    opencv/2.4.1/include
12. Cleared the search field and entered:

    Other Linker Flags
13. Double clicked in the empty space right of *Other Linker Flags* and inserted:

    -lopencv_core -lopencv_flann -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_lapack -lopencv_contrib

Ok this was the preparation as I read on an article online. Now I selected AppDelegate.h and added the following include (before the #import of Cocoa/Cocoa.h):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

Now here's the problem. I get this error from the XCode Code-sense:

```
'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found
```

At this point I have no clue why this is not working. I hope some experienced XCode user knows why this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote sounds right.
I just checked one of my OpenCV Xcode projects and all seems pretty much identical.
The only thing I didn't do is copying the libraries into my project folder ( I'm just linking them )
and adding the additional linker flags. Instead I was adding all the frameworks needed into the Xcode project.

I still couldn't find out why, but I was having the exact same issue you are describing as long as my current build architecture is set to 32 bit!!

Try changing your scheme to "My Mac 64 Bit" ( that's the default name, dunno if you changed it) and try to build again.

---

Here is a link to a "demo" Xcode project that works fine for me:

http://www.rapidshare.com/files/1391580878/Xcode_OpenCV_example.zip

Hope this helps,

best,

Flo

Comment: Hi Flo, thanks for you answer. My XCode already runs 64-bit only, so that's not the case :). I also tried the external variant, but also end up with the same reference error.
Looking at the Code-sense error I would assume I set the core path to OpenCV wrong, as it can't find it while using #include. I gonna see if I can do some more tests.

Comment: In case you can't solve the issue, I could offer you to upload an empty running project on a one-click hoster ( preferably Rapidshare ) where you can download it.

Comment: That would be awesome, thanks! Could you PM me a link? If I find the error in the difference I'll post it in here again :)

Comment: I posted the link in my original answer. Thought this might also come in handy for other guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to do that all step, I have set opncv in my project as:

1. add opencv2.framework into your project
2. add this code into your .pch file

   #ifndef __cplusplus

   #include < opencv2/opencv.hpp>

   #endif
3. Now Main Step which is ignored by all and get problem:change extension of all the .m files in which you want to use opencv  to .mm